# Usage of URL and URLConnection classes in Java

Tags: java, http, url, get

I was looking for an easy way to do a GET request given a URL, port and path. I came across this method which works fine but I started wondering why it is designed to be like this verbose. Why isn't it better for the URL class to provide a get() method that just does steps 2,3 and 4 behind the scenes?

```
    URL url = new URL("http", host, port, path);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about. Where do you see redundant data and/or steps?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of having a url.get() method that includes:
                   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                   conn.setDoInput(true);

                   conn.connect();

Comment: You are actually asking why the API is not more high level than it already is. This is just the way it was designed; having a higher level API would prevent developers from accessing many other options that are available now. You can still write your own wrapper !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the Apache HttpClient is a better replacement of URLConnection. The HttpClient has been integrated into Android API and it is more friendly to developer. More can be seen at http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 0):

`url.openStream()` bypasses the need for a self-managed URLConnection object.